# How to make _lodash.zip with less code

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

Definition：Creates an array of grouped elements, the first of which contains the first elements of the given arrays, the second of which contains the second elements of the given arrays, and so on.

Current Solution：

```
 const zip = (...arr) => { 
     let maxLength = 0 
     let res = [] 
     for (let el of arr) { 
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, el.length) 
     } 
     for (let j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) { 
        const foo = [] 
        for (let n of arr) { 
           foo.push(n[j]) 
        } 
        res.push(foo) 
     } 
     return res 
  }
```

Test Case:

```
test(('zip', () => {
  expect(zip([1, 2], [4, 5], [9, 1])).toEqual([[1, 4, 9], [2, 5, 1]])
}

test('zip', () => {
  expect(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])).toEqual([[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]])
})

test('zip', () => {
  expect(zip([1, 2], [], [3, 4, 5])).toEqual([
    [1, undefined, 3],
    [2, undefined, 4],
    [undefined, undefined, 5],
  ])
})
```

I want to get a better way to achieve zip, current solution is ugly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) If you need to add code to your question (and you do), use the "edit" link and format it properly, don't post it in a comment. Also, make it clear what you're asking. Does the code work? If it doesn't work, *how* does it not work? What have you found when debugging it to try to make it work? Etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ Terry How to make a _lodash.zip with a better way

Comment: That's not a good question. What is your current problem that needs to be solved, and why? You can't expect people to be mindreaders ;-)

Comment: @ cbll Sorry about that, I already update my question and description

Answer (score 0):

See [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info.

```js
// Proof.
const zip = (...args) => [...new Array(Math.max(...args.map(arr => arr.length)))].map((x, i) => args.map((y) => y[i]))

// Proof.
console.log(zip([1, 2], [4, 5], [9, 1])) // [[1, 4, 9], [2, 5, 1]]
console.log(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])) // [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
console.log(zip([1, 2], [], [3, 4, 5])) // [[1, undefined, 3], [2, undefined, 4], [undefined, undefined, 5]]
```

Comment: That's failed by the third test case

Comment: Should pass now ✌️

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your answer